# How to set dateTimePickerValue to null or empty in c#

Tags: c#, combobox, datetimepicker

I have a windows form of controls combobox and datetimepicker..
I have given null or empty to combobox  in page load..
so combobox shows empty intially while loading database values to it in windows form..
but the problem is
because of the datetimepicker is not kept to null or empty my form is showing message box as "the day is already existed" before form is desplaying..here my code follows

I want to show that message after combobox value is selected..

```
    try
       {
           ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
           string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
           SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
           cn.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select employee_id,employee_name from Employee_Details", cn);


           SqlDataReader dtr;
           dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();


           dt.Columns.Add("employee_id", typeof(string));
           dt.Columns.Add("employee_name", typeof(string));
           dt.Load(dtr);



           comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_id";
           comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
           comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

           comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
           if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
           {
               txtemployeeid.Text = "";
               txtemployeename.Text = "";

           }

           cn.Close();
       }

       catch (Exception e1)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);

       }

  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
        string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
        cn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select employee_id,Employee_name from Employee_Details where employee_name=('" + comboBox1.Text + "')", cn);
            SqlDataReader dtr;

             dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           if (dtr.Read())
            {


                string employee_id = (string)dtr["employee_id"];
                string employee_name = (string)dtr["employee_name"];
                txtemployeeid.Text = employee_id;
                txtemployeename.Text = employee_name;
                dtr.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            try
            {

                string dtp = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select date from dailyattendance where date=('" + dtp + "') and employee_id='" + txtemployeeid.Text + "' and empployee_name='" + txtemployeename.Text + "' ", cn);
                SqlDataReader dtr1;
                dtr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                if (dtr1.Read())
                {
                    string date = (string)dtr1["date"];
                    if (dtp == date)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("this day is already existed");
                    }
                }
                dtr1.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
            }
        }

        cn.Close();
    }
```

can any one solve it please..Thanx in advance

Comment: First thing to fix, before *anything* else: stop building SQL queries like that. Use parameterized queries, to avoid SQL injection attacks, conversion issues, etc. Next, use `using` statements to close connections, readers etc.

Comment: I dont know how to build parameterized quires
please modify it using parameterized quires and for conversion issues etc add here 
I use that code next onwards

Comment: Then now is a good time to learn, before you create an application with a SQL injection vulnerability. Look at the documentation for `SqlCommand.Parameters` as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use dtr.Text="";